# Qt - QPixmap to XML and conversely

Tags: c++, image, qt

Is there a way to save an image as "text" and then read it back? Indeed I'm using Qt and I'm trying to save/read a base64-encoded representation of a pixmap but nothing works as expected. Here is my current implementation sprinkled with several comments:

```
/*
 * the culprit pixmap
 */

QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap(a_given_jpg_filepath);

/*
 * pixmap to array of bytes
 */

QByteArray bytes;
QBuffer buffer(&bytes);
buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
pixmap.save(&buffer, "jpg"); // writes pixmap into bytes in jpg format

/*
 * byte array to text
 * this string is saved to xml (among others) and then read back
 */
const QString &str(bytes.toBase64()); // a base64-encoded version of the pixmap

/*
 * now trying to construct the pixmap (having it encoded as base64)
 */

const auto wantConversion = true;
if(wantConversion) {
    const QByteArray &bytes = QByteArray::fromBase64(str.toLatin1());
    QPixmap(bytes); // this pixmap is not the same as the previous one
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I on the right route to the solution? Any fix/remark is welcome.

Comment: You're on the right track. I've not used QBuffer, but your code matches the example in the docs. I would try comparing the before and after bytes arrays to see if the data going in is an exact match to the data going out. I suspect something is going wrong in the conversion, but I don't see any obvious error. I've done exactly this technique but with my own Base64 encoding routines, so I know that the concept works.

Comment: I indeed need to call `QPixmap::loadFromData` -> see @tntxtnt comment below. Everything works now.

Comment: Ah, I was also misreading the purpose of the constructor you were using. Just didn't read closely enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `loadFromData()`

```
const QByteArray &bytes = QByteArray::fromBase64(str.toLatin1());
QPixmap fromBase64;
fromBase64.loadFromData(bytes);
```